# I need to print this shape in c++ but I am having issue with last row

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

[image of shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPff5.png)

I have no issues with first 4 rows. 5th row is the problem. I am required to use loops but dont know how i am suppose to print 6 (-.*) with 0 spaces when all rows above follow a pattern.

Comment: please post text as text and include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: FWIW, the pattern that I see is rows with a decreasing number of `"   "` strings and an increasing number of `"-.*"` strings.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 28 - i * 3; j >= 0; j--) {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        std::cout << "-.*";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (i == 4) i++;
}
```

Basically check when you are on the 4th row and just have it skip a row by incrementing your row index loop.

Comment: how did you figure out "28 - i * 3" part

Comment: The `28` was just me eyballing how far it looked justified to the right. The `- i * 3` is how many less spaces it should be for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
std::string repeat(std::string s, int n) {
  std::string repeat;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    repeat += s;
  return repeat;
}

int main()
{
    int PADDING = 20; 
    int MAX = 7;
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if (i == 5) continue;

        std::string padding(3*(PADDING-MAX-i), ' ');
        
        std::cout << padding << repeat("-.*", i)  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
                                -.*
                             -.*-.*
                          -.*-.*-.*
                       -.*-.*-.*-.*
                 -.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*
```

Live demo:

http://cpp.sh/6mtpx

Comment: thats not printing the desired output

Answer (score 0):

In C  (not C++):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 5;
    char txt[3*height+1];
    char sym[]= "-.*";
    for(int i=0; i<3*height; ++i) txt[i]=sym[i%3];
    txt[3*height]=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    printf("%s%*.*s\n", (i+1==height)? &txt[3*(height-1)] : "", 3*(height+(i+1<height)), (i+1)*3, txt);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5476KB
               -.*
            -.*-.*
         -.*-.*-.*
      -.*-.*-.*-.*
-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/QyhX7y)